# What is the best strategy to read data (i.e., when using CSOM), if the current user is not having permissions on the list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am using SPServices(Javascript Library) to read Sharepoint list data on the client side (i.e., Mainly '/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'). Everything was fine till I have read permissions on the Sharepoint List.

Suddenly when the permissions are removed on a couple of lists, my code begins to fail as the code is getting executed with the current users context.

I wanted to (a) execute the code with elevated privileges (b) at the same time allow my client only to read the data.

I had some idea like to have a SOAP Wrapper Service for 'Sharepoint List Service' (i.e., Lists.asmx) where I consume the original service (i.e., Lists.asmx) and the code block gets executed with elevated privileges. Now, the SPService calls will be replaced with calls to my custom SOAP service. But, I am not sure how to implement the same.

At the same time I feel the above solution may solve only problem (a) but the problem (b) remains still.

What is the best strategy to read data even if no privileges are assigned to a list for the current user as the data is sensitive?

Please help me in addressing the above situation. Quick response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you run code with elevated privileges, it will have ALL permissions, you have to take care yourself to avoid any unwanted Actions.

All you could do is create a user, which has read Access to the requested lists and run the Service-Wrapper under that user (you would have to find a way to impersonate the user)

The best strategy is, to give the users Read Permission if they should be able to read the data.

Comment: +1 for this "The best strategy is, to give the users Read Permission if they should be able to read the data." Use the platform the way it should, introducing custom code to get around a read operation vexes me to no end.

Comment: I cannot allow users to even have read permissions on the list. Most of the columns in the list have sensitive data. I am showing only some columns of the list which is not sensitive on the UI.

Comment: you don´t want to give users read access because of sensitive data but you consider a wrapping service for lists.asmx, available for anyone and giving anyone full permissions on all Lists in the sharepoint-farm?

maybe a better solution is to build a second list, where insensitive data is synced from the "sensivite list" that provides the information for the "ReadOnly" users.There would be only a need for a TimerJob or an Eventreceiver and would be quite easier to implement (and better in means of security)